# Azure WebJob Schedule

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

There is an Azure web job created by someone in my project that has the following details.

XyzTasks   -->   Triggered   -->  Completed 56 min ago  -->   n/a

This job runs every hour but the schedule is shown as n/a in the portal. I checked Kudo console to see if there are any settings.job file available but nothing found. Could you please tell me how this job was created as Triggered with schedule when i am not able to see any scheduling details?

Comment: Maybe triggered with Azure Scheduler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as Juunas mentioned it's indeed triggered from Azure Schedule. Refer the blog http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html for more details on this.

In the solution explorer you'll need to change the properties of that settings.job file and set the Copy to output directory to Copy always. This will make sure the file is in the root directory of the WebJob.

Additionally, check the (You may wish to know) [Differences between the two scheduled WebJobs](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/#.WkPJIN-Waql)

Azure Scheduler
Pros
•   Doesn't require the website to be configured as Always On.
•   Supported by Visual Studio tooling and the current Azure portal.
Cons
•   Doesn't support continuous integration - to schedule a job or reschedule a job you'll need access to your Azure account.
•   Loosely tied to the triggered WebJob, you cannot always tell that a WebJob has an Azure Scheduler job behind it.

Internal WebJob Scheduler

Pros
•   Supports continuous integration and any deployment mechanism available for Azure Web Apps as it is file based.
•   Supports the common cron expressions.
•   Can tell a WebJob is scheduled with a simple api call.
Cons
•   Requires Always On.
•   Not yet supported by tooling and portal (hopefully that will change).